# Haskell: Splitting pipes (broadcast) without using spawn

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

This question is a bit codegolf and a lot newb.

I'm using the awesome `pipes` library in Haskell, and I'd like to split a pipe to send the same data along multiple channels (do a broadcast).
The [`Pipes.Concurrent` tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.1/docs/Pipes-Concurrent-Tutorial.html) suggests using `spawn` to create mailboxes, taking advantage of `Output`'s monoid status.
For example, we might do something like this:

```
main = do
 (output1, input1) <- spawn Unbounded
 (output2, input2) <- spawn Unbounded
 let effect1 = fromInput input1 >-> pipe1
 let effect2 = fromInput input2 >-> pipe2
 let effect3 = P.stdinLn >-> toOutput (output1 <> output2)
 ...
```

Is this indirection through the mailboxes really necessary?
Could we instead write something like this?

```
main = do
 let effect3 = P.stdinLn >-> (pipe1 <> pipe2)
 ...
```

The above doesn't compile, because `Pipe` doesn't have a `Monoid` instance.
Is there a good reason for this?
Is the first method really the cleanest way to split a pipe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to do this without using concurrency, both with caveats.

The first way is that if `pipe1` and `pipe2` are just simple `Consumer`s that loop forever like:

```
p1 = for cat f  -- i.e. p1 = forever $ await >>= f
p2 = for cat g  -- i.e. p2 = forever $ await >>= g
```

... then the easy way to solve this is to just write:

```
for P.stdinLn $ \str -> do
    f str
    g str
```

For example, if `p1` is just `print`ing every value:

```
p1 = for cat (lift . print)
```

... and `p2` is just writing that value to a handle:

```
p2 = for cat (lift . hPutStrLn h)
```

... then you would combine them like so:

```
for P.stdinLn $ \str -> do
    lift $ print str
    lift $ hPutStrLn h str
```

However, this simplification only works for `Consumer`s that trivially loop.  There's another solution that is more general, which is to define an `ArrowChoice` instance for pipes.  I believe that pull-based `Pipe`s do not permit a correct law-abiding instance, but push-based `Pipe`s do:

```
newtype Edge m r a b = Edge { unEdge :: a -> Pipe a b m r }

instance (Monad m) => Category (Edge m r) where
    id = Edge push
    (Edge p2) . (Edge p1) = Edge (p1 >~> p2)

instance (Monad m) => Arrow (Edge m r) where
    arr f = Edge (push />/ respond . f)
    first (Edge p) = Edge $ \(b, d) ->
        evalStateP d $ (up \>\ unsafeHoist lift . p />/ dn) b
      where
        up () = do
            (b, d) <- request ()
            lift $ put d
            return b
        dn c = do
            d <- lift get
            respond (c, d)

instance (Monad m) => ArrowChoice (Edge m r) where
    left (Edge k) = Edge (bef >=> (up \>\ (k />/ dn)))
      where
          bef x = case x of
              Left b -> return b
              Right d -> do
                  _ <- respond (Right d)
                  x2 <- request ()
                  bef x2
          up () = do
              x <- request ()
              bef x
          dn c = respond (Left c)
```

This requires a newtype so that the type parameters are in the order that `ArrowChoice` expects.

If you're unfamiliar with the term push-based `Pipe`, it's basically a `Pipe` that begins from the most upstream pipe instead of the most downstream pipe, and they all have the following shape:

```
a -> Pipe a b m r
```

Think of it as a `Pipe` that cannot "go" until it receives at least one value from upstream.

These push-based `Pipe`s are the "dual" to conventional pull-based `Pipe`s, complete with their own composition operator and identity:

```
(>~>) :: (Monad m)
      => (a -> Pipe a b m r)
      -> (b -> Pipe b c m r)
      -> (a -> Pipe a c m r)

push  :: (Monad m)
      ->  a -> Pipe a a m r
```

... but the unidirectional `Pipes` API does not export this by default.  You can only get these operators from `Pipes.Core` (and you may want to study that module more closely to build an intuition for how they work).  That module shows that both push-based `Pipe`s and pull-based `Pipe`s are both special cases of more general bidirectional versions, and understanding the bidirectional case is how you learn why they are duals of each other.

Once you have an `Arrow` instance for push-based pipes, you can write something like:

```
p >>> bifurcate >>> (p1 +++ p2)
  where
    bifurcate = Edge $ pull ~> \a -> do
        yield (Left  a)  -- First give `p1` the value
        yield (Right a)  -- Then give `p2` the value
```

Then you would use `runEdge` to convert that to a pull-based pipe when you are done.

This approach has one major draw-back, which is that you can't automatically upgrade a pull-based pipe to a push-based pipe (but usually it's not hard to figure out how to do it manually).  For example, to upgrade `Pipes.Prelude.map` to be a push-based `Pipe`, you would write:

```
mapPush :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> (a -> Pipe a b m r)
mapPush f a = do
    yield (f a)
    Pipes.Prelude.map f
```

Then that has the right type to be wrapped up in the `Arrow`:

```
mapEdge :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> Edge m r a b
mapEdge f = Edge (mapPush f)
```

Of course, an even simpler way would be just to write it from scratch:

```
mapEdge f = Edge $ push ~> yield . f
```

Use whichever approach suits you best.

In fact, I came up with the `Arrow` and `ArrowChoice` instances precisely because I was trying to answer the exact same question as you: how do you solve these kinds of problems without using concurrency?  I wrote up a long answer about this more general subject in another Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201901/in-functional-reactive-programming-how-do-you-share-state-between-two-parts-of/19204253#19204253), where I describe how you can use these `Arrow` and `ArrowChoice` instances to distill concurrent systems into equivalent pure ones.