# Single-stepping a conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit

I want to do something along the lines of ArrowChoice, but with [conduits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit). I want to await an Either value and then pass Left values to one conduit and Right values to another, and then merge the results back into an Either stream.

Presumably this can be done by making the inner conduits like automata: turn a conduit into a function that takes an argument and returns a monadic list of outputs yielded:

```
newtype AutomataM i m o = Automata (i -> m (o, Automata i o))

conduitStep :: Conduit i m o -> AutomataM i m [o]
```

The reason for the list of outputs is that a Conduit may yield 0 or more outputs for each input.

I've looked at ResumableConduit and its relatives, and presumably the answer is in there somewhere. But I can't quite see how its done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly the same type signature you provided, but:

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Internal (Pipe (..), ConduitM (..))

newtype Automata i o m r = Automata (m ([o], Either r (i -> Automata i o m r)))

conduitStep :: Monad m => ConduitM i o m r -> Automata i o m r
conduitStep (ConduitM con0) =
    Automata $ go [] id con0
  where
    go _ front (Done r) = return (front [], Left r)
    go ls front (HaveOutput p _ o) = go ls (front . (o:)) p
    go ls front (NeedInput p _) =
        case ls of
            [] -> return (front [], Right $ conduitStep . ConduitM . p)
            l:ls' -> go ls' front (p l)
    go ls front (PipeM mp) = mp >>= go ls front
    go ls front (Leftover p l) = go (l:ls) front p
```

But just be careful with this approach:

1. By keeping the output as a list, it's not constant memory.
2. We're throwing away finalizers.

There's probably a way to provide a `ZipConduit` abstraction, similar to `ZipSource` and `ZipSink`, that would handle this kind of problem more elegantly, but I haven't thought about it too much.

---

**EDIT** I ended up implementing `ZipConduit` in conduit-extra 0.1.5. Here's a demonstration of using it which sounds a bit like your case:

```
import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.Conduit
import           Data.Conduit.Extra
import qualified Data.Conduit.List   as CL

conduit1 :: Monad m => Conduit Int m String
conduit1 = CL.map $ \i -> "conduit1: " ++ show i

conduit2 :: Monad m => Conduit Double m String
conduit2 = CL.map $ \d -> "conduit2: " ++ show d

conduit :: Monad m => Conduit (Either Int Double) m String
conduit = getZipConduit $
    ZipConduit (lefts =$= conduit1) *>
    ZipConduit (rights =$= conduit2)
  where
    lefts = CL.mapMaybe (either Just (const Nothing))
    rights = CL.mapMaybe (either (const Nothing) Just)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let src = do
            yield $ Left 1
            yield $ Right 2
            yield $ Left 3
            yield $ Right 4
        sink = CL.mapM_ putStrLn
    src $$ conduit =$ sink
```

Comment: The method is presumably not as powerful, but given pipe1 and pipe2 like conduit1 and conduit2, and `inputs = each [Left 1, Right 2, Left 3, Right 4]`, the pipes equivalent of this program is `main = runEffect $ inputs >-> for (pipe1 +++ pipe2) (either P.yield P.yield) >-> P.stdoutLn` It uses `(+++)` from pipes-extras. There are other analyses of the problem of course.

Comment: For people reading this later, `ZipConduit` [is now in the `conduit` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.2/docs/Data-Conduit.html#g:19).

Answer (score 1):

There's a folk method of doing this using `pipes` by using "push-category" Pipes. The complete implementation comes from both [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-pipes/H6YdVhyNksk) and [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758744/haskell-splitting-pipes-broadcast-without-using-spawn). I think it hasn't been released yet due to both an effort to simplify the `Pipes` interface, a focus on using the "sequencing" monad instance which is hidden via this method, and no proof yet that this implementation truly implements the Arrow class properly.

The idea is to implement a newtype `Edge` (demonstrated below) which is a push-based pipe with the type arguments in the right order for `Category`, `Arrow`, `ArrowChoice` and both `Functor` and `Applicative` over their output values. This lets you compose them into directed acyclic graphs using arrow notation. I'll run over the implementation below, but it's safe to just ignore it and use the `Arrow`/`ArrowChoice`/`Applicative` instances of `Edge` without too much concern.

(*Edit:* This code is best made available at https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-RCPL-Library)

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Pipes.Core
import Pipes.Lift
import Control.Monad.Morph
import Control.Category
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Arrow
```

This is an atypical mode of using pipes and isn't exposed in the `Pipes` module; you must import `Pipes.Core` to use `push`. Push-based pipes look like

```
-- push :: a -> Proxy a' a a' a m r
```

and thus they demand at least one upstream value before the `Proxy` is allowed to run. This means the whole process needs to be "kickstarted" by passing the first value as a function call and that the leftmost push-`Proxy` will control the entire stream.

Given a push-based pipe we can implement `Category`, `Arrow` and `ArrowChoice`. The standard solution also involves the `Edge` typeclass so that we have the type arguments in the right order for `Category` and `Arrow`

```
newtype Edge m r a b = Edge { unEdge :: a -> Pipe a b m r }
```

For the `Category` instance, we use the "push" Category which has `push` as `id` and `(<~<)` as composition:

```
instance Monad m => Category (Edge m r) where
  id = Edge push
  Edge a . Edge b = Edge (a <~< b)
```

We embed functions into `Edge` with `arr` by augmenting `id` (i.e. `push`) on the downward edge. To do this we use the `respond` category which has the law `p />/ respond == p`, but jam our `f` into the process.

```
instance Monad m => Arrow (Edge m r) where
  arr f = Edge (push />/ respond . f)
```

We also use a local state transformer to store the `snd` half of our pairs and pass it "around" the input pipe in `first`

```
  first (Edge p) = Edge $ \(b, d) ->
    evalStateP d $ (up \>\ hoist lift . p />/ dn) b
    where
      up () = do
        (b, d) <- request ()
        lift (put d)
        return b
      dn c = do
        d <- lift get
        respond (c, d)
```

Finally, we get an `ArrowChoice` instance by implementing `left`. To do so we split the burden of passing the `Left` and `Right` sides using either the return or the pipe to pass values.

```
instance (Monad m) => ArrowChoice (Edge m r) where
    left (Edge k) = Edge (bef >=> (up \>\ (k />/ dn)))
      where
          bef x = case x of
              Left b -> return b
              Right d -> do
                  _ <- respond (Right d)
                  x2 <- request ()
                  bef x2
          up () = do
              x <- request ()
              bef x
          dn c = respond (Left c)
```

We can use `Edge` to create "push-based" producers and consumers

```
type PProducer m r b =            Edge m r () b
type PConsumer m r a = forall b . Edge m r a  b
```

and then we'll provide `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for `PProducer`. This goes by `case` analysis on the underlying `Pipe`, so it's a bit verbose. Essentially, however, all that happens is that we insert `f` into the `yield` slot of the `Pipe`.

```
instance Functor (PProducer m r) where
  fmap f (Edge k) = $ Edge $ \() -> go (k ()) where
    go p = case p of
      Request () ku -> Request ()    (\() -> go (ku ()))
      -- This is the only interesting line
      Respond b  ku -> Respond (f b) (\() -> go (ku ()))
      M          m  -> M (m >>= \p' -> return (go p'))  
      Pure    r     -> Pure r
```

Finally, `Applicative` is much the same except that we have to switch between running the upstream pipe to produce functions and running the downstream pipe to produce arguments.

```
instance (Monad m) => Applicative (Edge m r ()) where
    pure b = Edge $ \() -> forever $ respond b
    (Edge k1) <*> (Edge k2) = Edge (\() -> goL (k1 ()) (k2 ()))
      where
        goL p1 p2 = case p1 of
            Request () ku -> Request () (\() -> goL   (ku ()) p2)
            Respond f  ku ->                    goR f (ku ()) p2
            M          m  -> M (m >>= \p1' -> return (goL p1' p2))
            Pure    r     -> Pure r
        goR f p1 p2 = case p2 of
            Request () ku -> Request ()    (\() -> goR f p1 (ku ()))
            Respond x  ku -> Respond (f x) (\() -> goL   p1 (ku ()))
            M          m  -> M (m >>= \p2' -> return (goR f p1 p2'))
            Pure    r     -> Pure r
```