# Pipes choice without pattern matching

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

This is closely related to Gabriel's response to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758744/haskell-splitting-pipes-broadcast-without-using-spawn). I have written a function that provides something like the `|||` function from `ArrowChoice` but for a `Proxy` (from the `pipes` library). It pattern matches and has five mutually recursive functions. I'd like to find an alternative implementation that uses the function from `Pipes.Core` instead of pattern matching.

I first tried adapted the implementation of `left` in the other answer. It looks like this:

```
newtype Edge m r a b = Edge { unEdge :: a -> Pipe a b m r }

instance (Monad m) => ArrowChoice (Edge m r) where
  left (Edge k) = Edge (bef >=> (up \>\ (k />/ dn)))
    where
      bef x = case x of
          Left b -> return b
          Right d -> do
              _ <- respond (Right d)
              x2 <- request ()
              bef x2
      up () = do
          x <- request ()
          bef x
      dn c = respond (Left c)
```

However, this implementation relies on upstream out and downstream in being the same, and I could not see a way to generalize it further. The closest I could get was:

```
proxyLeft :: Monad m
  => (a -> Pipes.Proxy y a y b m r)
  -> Either a x
  -> Pipes.Proxy y (Either a x) y (Either b x) m r
proxyLeft k = bef >=> (up \>\ (k />/ dn))
  where
  bef x = case x of
    Left b -> return b
    Right d -> do
      a <- respond (Right d)
      x2 <- request a
      bef x2
  up a = do
    x <- request a
    bef x
  dn c = respond (Left c)
```

The code snippet for my variant of `|||` is pretty long, and I am only providing it as evidence that this can be done in some fashion. The function is named `downstreamOr`. All of the other functions are just mutually recursive helper functions:

```
downstreamOr ::
     Monad m
  => (b' -> Pipes.Proxy a' a b' b m r)
  -> (c' -> Pipes.Proxy a' a c' b m r)
  -> Either b' c'
  -> Pipes.Proxy a' a (Either b' c') b m r
downstreamOr f g e = case e of
  Left b' -> case f b' of
    Pipes.Request a' k -> Pipes.Request a' (downstreamOrLeft k g)
    Pipes.Respond b k -> Pipes.Respond b (downstreamOr k g)
    Pipes.M m -> Pipes.M $ m >>= \p -> return $ downstreamLeftM p g
    Pipes.Pure r -> Pipes.Pure r
  Right c' -> case g c' of
    Pipes.Request a' k -> Pipes.Request a' (downstreamOrRight f k)
    Pipes.Respond b k -> Pipes.Respond b (downstreamOr f k)
    Pipes.M m -> Pipes.M $ m >>= \p -> return $ downstreamRightM f p
    Pipes.Pure r -> Pipes.Pure r

downstreamOrLeft ::
     Monad m
  => (a -> Pipes.Proxy a' a b' b m r)
  -> (c' -> Pipes.Proxy a' a c' b m r)
  -> a
  -> Pipes.Proxy a' a (Either b' c') b m r
downstreamOrLeft f g a = case f a of
  Pipes.Request a' k -> Pipes.Request a' (downstreamOrLeft k g)
  Pipes.Respond b k -> Pipes.Respond b (downstreamOr k g)
  Pipes.M m -> Pipes.M $ m >>= \p -> return $ downstreamLeftM p g
  Pipes.Pure r -> Pipes.Pure r

downstreamOrRight ::
     Monad m
  => (b' -> Pipes.Proxy a' a b' b m r)
  -> (a -> Pipes.Proxy a' a c' b m r)
  -> a
  -> Pipes.Proxy a' a (Either b' c') b m r
downstreamOrRight f g a = case g a of
  Pipes.Request a' k -> Pipes.Request a' (downstreamOrRight f k)
  Pipes.Respond b k -> Pipes.Respond b (downstreamOr f k)
  Pipes.M m -> Pipes.M $ m >>= \p -> return $ downstreamRightM f p
  Pipes.Pure r -> Pipes.Pure r

downstreamLeftM ::
     Monad m
  => Pipes.Proxy a' a b' b m r
  -> (c' -> Pipes.Proxy a' a c' b m r)
  -> Pipes.Proxy a' a (Either b' c') b m r
downstreamLeftM p g = case p of
  Pipes.Pure r -> Pipes.Pure r
  Pipes.Request a' k -> Pipes.Request a' (downstreamOrLeft k g)
  Pipes.Respond b k -> Pipes.Respond b (downstreamOr k g)
  Pipes.M m -> Pipes.M $ m >>= \p -> return $ downstreamLeftM p g

downstreamRightM ::
     Monad m
  => (b' -> Pipes.Proxy a' a b' b m r)
  -> Pipes.Proxy a' a c' b m r
  -> Pipes.Proxy a' a (Either b' c') b m r
downstreamRightM f p = case p of
  Pipes.Pure r -> Pipes.Pure r
  Pipes.Respond a' k -> Pipes.Respond a' (downstreamOr f k)
  Pipes.Request a' k -> Pipes.Request a' (downstreamOrRight f k)
  Pipes.M m -> Pipes.M $ m >>= \p -> return $ downstreamRightM f p
```

It would be helpful to see how either of these can be implemented without pattern matching. Thanks, and let me know if I can clarify anything.